# What is the simplest way to say "the whole thing" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

What is the simplest way to say "the whole thing" in German?

I used the word "vollständiger" in the following computer programme:

```
vollständiger_text = """    
    cloud    
    fog    
    fumes    
    miasma    
    mist    
    murk    
    smog    
    steam    
    water vapor    
"""    
words = vollständiger_text.split()
```

The word `"fog"` is one of many words inside of the *vollständiger text*  (**The whole thing**).

I want to replace the phrase *vollständiger text*  with a German phrase for **The whole thing**.

I worry that the word "*vollständiger*" is too fancy.  How would a child say, "***the whole thing***", or what is the simplest way to say the "the whole thing" in German?

Comment: nevermind an actual answer, but using anything but english variable names in a computer program ist considered bad style and should be avoided.

Comment: @infinitezero I don't think that is true. It depends for whom you write the sources. It's not something I prefer to do, but I wouldn't consider it bad style

Answer (score 1):

"The whole thing" would be "Das ganze Ding", "die Gesamtheit" (entirety) or maybe even "alles" (everything).

It's tempting to go on a tangent about variable naming, because all of these are actually worse than "vollständiger_text", which is at least somewhat expressive in comparison. Depending on the scope of this variable, it would probably be better to use a name that describes the variable from a business logic perspective rather than a completely technical one, like "wasserdampf_mehrzeilig" or something like that. But, of course, this is offtopic in German Language SE.

Other more expressive but technical ideas: "wortliste_zeilen", "alle_wörter", "liste_textform", ...

Answer (score 0):

In the given context my choice would be

> Text

since this matches the common expectation, that a text consists of words.

In general a compound substantive with *Gesamt* as first part could be found, but I can't recommend the direct translation *Ding* as second part.